# How to implement pagination with a limited number of pages visible and Previous and Next page buttons

Tags: php, pagination

I have written a pagination code in PHP which displays all page numbers at once. I want to limit the number of pages shown by the script so when there are 200 pages, only the first 10 pages will be visible when the first one is selected. Then I want to add Previous and Next page buttons to switch between active pages.

```css
<style>
    .btn-page{
        padding:5px 10px; 
        border: #CCC 1px solid; 
        background:#FFF; 
        border-radius:4px;
        cursor:pointer;
        }
    .btn-page:hover{background:#F0F0F0;}
    .btn-page.current{background:#ABB2B9;}
</style>
```

```php
/* Pagination Code starts */
$per_page_html = '';
$page = 1;
$start=0;
if(!empty($_POST["page"])) {
    $page = $_POST["page"];
    $start=($page-1) * ROW_PER_PAGE;
}
$limit=" limit " . $start . "," . ROW_PER_PAGE;
$pagination_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
$pagination_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pagination_statement->execute();

$row_count = $pagination_statement->rowCount();
if(!empty($row_count)){
    $per_page_html .= "<div style='text-align:center;margin:20px 0px;'>";
    $page_count=ceil($row_count/ROW_PER_PAGE);
    if($page_count>1) {
        for($i=1;$i<=$page_count;$i++){
            if($i==$page){
                $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page current" />';
            } else {
                $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page" />';
            }
        }
    }
    $per_page_html .= "</div>";
}

$query = $sql.$limit;
$pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
$pdo_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo_statement->execute();
$result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'Previous' and 'Next' before and after the for loop respectively.

See the code below:

```
<style>
.btn-page{
    padding:5px 10px; 
    border: #CCC 1px solid; 
    background:#FFF; 
    border-radius:4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
.btn-page:hover{background:#F0F0F0;}
.btn-page.current{background:#ABB2B9;}
</style>


/* Pagination Code starts */
$per_page_html = '';
$page = 1;
$start=0;
if(!empty($_POST["page"])) {
    $page = $_POST["page"];
    $start=($page-1) * ROW_PER_PAGE;
}
$limit=" limit " . $start . "," . ROW_PER_PAGE;
$pagination_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
$pagination_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pagination_statement->execute();

$row_count = $pagination_statement->rowCount();
if(!empty($row_count)){
    $per_page_html .= "<div style='text-align:center;margin:20px 0px;'>";
    $page_count=ceil($row_count/ROW_PER_PAGE);
    if($page_count>1) {
        $prevpage = 1;
        $nextpage = $page_count;
        if($page_count> 10){
            $prevpage = ($page-5>0)?($page-5):1;
            $nextpage = ($page+5<=$page_count)?($page+5):$page_count;
        }
        if($page>1){
            $per_page_html .= '<button type="submit" name="page" value="1" class="btn-page" >First Page</button><button type="submit" name="page" value="'.($page-1).'" class="btn-page" >Previous Page</button>';
        } 
        for($i=$prevpage;$i<=$nextpage;$i++){
            if($i==$page){
                $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page current" />';
            } else {
                $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page" />';
            }
        }
        if($page<$page_count){
            $per_page_html .= '<button type="submit" name="page" value="'.($page+1).'" class="btn-page">Next Page</button><button type="submit" name="page" value="'.$page_count.'" class="btn-page" >Last Page</button>';
        }
    }
    $per_page_html .= "</div>";
}

$query = $sql.$limit;
$pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
$pdo_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo_statement->execute();
$result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190776/discussion-on-answer-by-nimit-shah-how-to-implement-pagination-with-a-limited-nu). Please make sure to [edit] the answer to include all relevant information..